# JSON returning to end of PHP code instead of mobile.html

Tags: javascript, php, json

My PHP file processes for both web and mobile. Javascript file directs the ajax/json to mobile.html. When using the mobile.html, JSON returns to the end of the PHP code, before the HTML code begins. [JSON returned to wrong HTML](http://i.stack.imgur.co)
I pasted the code affect. I am a student and let me apologize in advance if my post is confusing.

```js
function getProductPerdomo() {   
    var cigarName = "";
    var price = ""
    var supplyAmount = "";
 $.ajax({                 
         url: 'selectperdomo.php', 
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: "JSON",   
         data: {   
          mobile: "yes" 
         },
         success: function(json){   
   $.each(json, function(key, value){   
                cigarName = value.cigar_name;
                price = "Price: " + value.price;
                supplyAmount = "In Stock: " + value.supply;  
            });
         $('#perdomonamehere').html(cigarName);
         $('#perdomopricehere').html(price);
         $('#perdomosupplyhere').html(supplyAmount);  
        }
    })
}
```

```css
<?php
      $mobile = $_POST["mobile"]; 
   if ($mobile == "yes"){
     $price=199;
   $sql = "SELECT cigar_name, price, supply
              FROM product T1
              INNER JOIN inventory T2 ON T1.cigar_id=T2.cigar_id
                    WHERE price=$price";
      
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $data = array();   
   while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {    
    $data[] = $r;
      }
    echo json_encode($data);
   }else{
   
$_SESSION["price"] = 199;  
$_SESSION["cigar_id"] = 4;  //this is for perdomo

   $sql = "SELECT supply FROM inventory WHERE cigar_id=4";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     
         echo "<table> <tr>
                          <td>Number of Boxes in Stock:  " . $row["supply"] .   "  </td>
                          </tr>         
    </table>";
    }
   }
   else{
    echo "0 results";
   }
  } //end else  
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
```

```html
<div data-role="page" data-dialog="true"  id="perdomo">
  <div data-role="header">
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left" data-rel="back">Back</a>
  <h1>Products</h1>
  </div>
 <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
 <p id="perdomonamehere"></p>
 <p id="perdomopricehere"></p>
 <p>Box of 24</p>
 <p id="perdomosupplyhere"></p>
    <form method="post">
      <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
        <input type="number" name="quantity" id="perdomoquantity" >   
      </div>
      <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

m/e43qk.jpg

Comment: Your image link is broken

Comment: What are you expecting back from the selectperdomo.php file? JSON or HTML? You're outputting (or seemingly trying to) both, but an ajax call will only allow you to receive back 1 or the other. Your ajax call is indicating you want JSON back ( `dataType: "JSON"` )

Comment: Thanks Patrick Q.  The image showed the chrome developere tool Network  - JSON being returned to the end of the PHP code right before the HTML code starts.  The JSON data should have gone to the HTML I pasted above.

Comment: Josh KG - I am expecting JSON back.  JSON sends the name of the cigar, the price, and the supply. That data should post into the id="perdomonamehere" etc in the html above. However, in the PHP file, there is HTML for the web pages.  It's like the client is confused and doesn't know where to put it so it plops as json encoded data in the html file.

Comment: Thanks for everyone who helped. I moved a closing bracket to the end of the HTML and JSON returned to the right place. Closed.